# MySQL For each row with a column value A, add a new row with a column value B, if one does not already exist

Tags: mysql

I have a table with columns `id`, `foo_id`, and `bar_id`.

I want to go through the table and for each distinct `foo_id`, if there is a row for that `foo_id` with a `bar_id` equal to 2, I want to add a new row with that `foo_id` and with a `bar_id` equal to 3, unless a row with that `foo_id` and `bar_id` of 3 already exists.

For example:

Before:

```
id | foo_id | bar_id
--------------------
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 2
3  | 2      | 2
4  | 2      | 3
5  | 3      | 2
6  | 4      | 1
```

After:

```
id | foo_id | bar_id
--------------------
1  | 1      | 1
2  | 1      | 2
3  | 2      | 2
4  | 2      | 3
5  | 3      | 2
6  | 4      | 1
7  | 1      | 3
8  | 3      | 3
```

I've tried this query, but it's taking a really long time (>20 min) and I don't know if it works:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (bar_id, foo_id)
    SELECT 3, (@var := foo_id) AS foo_id FROM mytable
    WHERE bar_id=2 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM mytable
        WHERE bar_id=3 AND foo_id=@var
    ) LIMIT 1;
```

Does anyone know how to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 INSERT INTO mytable (bar_id, foo_id)
 SELECT 3, foo_id
 FROM mytable
 WHERE bar_id=2 AND foo_id NOT IN (
     SELECT foo_id FROM mytable WHERE bar_id=3 
 );
```

Comment: Nope, this will add a record with bar_id of 2 and foo_id of 3, which already exists (which I'm realizing now I specified as a requirement in the title but not in the description, I'll update)

Comment: @thanksd   give the right  specific .. and comment  me ..when done

Comment: Hmm this still adds a row for [bar_id=2, foo_id=3]. Doesn't the inner join just take out any rows where foo_id=3 from the select? That wouldn't affect which rows are inserted.